# Unable to use virtual Box on full screen

Tags: windows, ubuntu, virtual-machine, virtualbox

First of all, I'm using Virtual Box 4.1.4 to emulate Xubuntu 14.05.5 on a windows 7 computer.

I have some trouble to emulate Xubuntu in full screen on my VirtualBox, I tried a lot of solution i found on the internet, but none of them seems to work on my case.
On first, i tried to install it from the guest addition module, but i had this error :

> Building the main Guest Additions module ...fail!

https://askubuntu.com/questions/204098/error-building-main-guest-additions-module-while-installing-virtualbox-guest-add
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7xoHpIMPbIc

Then i tried to install virtualbox guest-x11 but it doesn't seem to change anything neither...
I'm kinda stuck right now, and I hope some of you could have a solution...

Thanks for all !

EDIT :

```
 `Verifying archive integrity... All good.
Uncompressing VirtualBox 4.1.4 Guest Additions for Linux.........
VirtualBox Guest Additions installer
Removing installed version 5.1.12 of VirtualBox Guest Additions...
vboxadd.sh: Stopping VirtualBox Additions.
You may need to restart your guest system to finish removing the guest drivers.
Removing existing VirtualBox DKMS kernel modules ...done.
Removing existing VirtualBox non-DKMS kernel modules ...done.
Building the VirtualBox Guest Additions kernel modules
The headers for the current running kernel were not found. If the following
module compilation fails then this could be the reason.

Building the main Guest Additions module ...fail!
(Look at /var/log/vboxadd-install.log to find out what went wrong)
Doing non-kernel setup of the Guest Additions ...done.
Installing the Window System drivers
Warning: unknown version of the X Window System installed.  Not installing
X Window System drivers.
Installing modules ...done.
Installing graphics libraries and desktop services components ...done.`
```

And the log file :

```
 Uninstalling modules from DKMS
Attempting to install using DKMS

Creating symlink /var/lib/dkms/vboxguest/4.1.4/source ->
                 /usr/src/vboxguest-4.1.4

DKMS: add completed.

Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel.  Skipping...

Building module:
cleaning build area....
make KERNELRELEASE=3.16.0-30-generic -C /lib/modules/3.16.0-30-generic/build M=/var/lib/dkms/vboxguest/4.1.4/build......(bad exit status: 2)
ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for vboxguest: 4.1.4 not found
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 3.16.0-30-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/vboxguest/4.1.4/build/make.log for more information.
Failed to install using DKMS, attempting to install without
grep: /lib/modules/3.16.0-30-generic/build/include/linux/version.h: No such file or directory
make KBUILD_VERBOSE=1 -C /lib/modules/3.16.0-30-generic/build SUBDIRS=/tmp/vbox.0 SRCROOT=/tmp/vbox.0 modules
test -e include/generated/autoconf.h -a -e include/config/auto.conf || (        \
    echo >&2;                           \
    echo >&2 "  ERROR: Kernel configuration is invalid.";       \
    echo >&2 "         include/generated/autoconf.h or include/config/auto.conf are missing.";\
    echo >&2 "         Run 'make oldconfig && make prepare' on kernel src to fix it.";  \
    echo >&2 ;                          \
    /bin/false)
mkdir -p /tmp/vbox.0/.tmp_versions ; rm -f /tmp/vbox.0/.tmp_versions/*
make -f scripts/Makefile.build obj=/tmp/vbox.0
  gcc -Wp,-MD,/tmp/vbox.0/.VBoxGuest-linux.o.d  -nostdinc -isystem /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/include  -I./arch/x86/include -Iarch/x86/include/generated  -Iinclude -I./arch/x86/include/uapi -Iarch/x86/include/generated/uapi -I./include/uapi -Iinclude/generated/uapi -include ./include/linux/kconfig.h -Iubuntu/include  -D__KERNEL__ -Wall -Wundef -Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-trigraphs -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -Werror-implicit-function-declaration -Wno-format-security -m64 -mno-mmx -mno-sse -mno-80387 -mno-fp-ret-in-387 -mpreferred-stack-boundary=3 -mtune=generic -mno-red-zone -mcmodel=kernel -funit-at-a-time -maccumulate-outgoing-args -DCONFIG_X86_X32_ABI -DCONFIG_AS_CFI=1 -DCONFIG_AS_CFI_SIGNAL_FRAME=1 -DCONFIG_AS_CFI_SECTIONS=1 -DCONFIG_AS_FXSAVEQ=1 -DCONFIG_AS_CRC32=1 -DCONFIG_AS_AVX=1 -DCONFIG_AS_AVX2=1 -pipe -Wno-sign-compare -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables -mno-sse -mno-mmx -mno-sse2 -mno-3dnow -mno-avx -fno-delete-null-pointer-checks -O2 -Wframe-larger-than=1024 -fstack-protector -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-optimize-sibling-calls -fno-var-tracking-assignments -pg -mfentry -DCC_USING_FENTRY -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wno-pointer-sign -fno-strict-overflow -fconserve-stack -Werror=implicit-int -Werror=strict-prototypes -DCC_HAVE_ASM_GOTO -include /tmp/vbox.0/include/VBox/VBoxGuestMangling.h -I/lib/modules/3.16.0-30-generic/build/include -I/tmp/vbox.0/ -I/tmp/vbox.0/include -I/tmp/vbox.0/r0drv/linux -I/tmp/vbox.0/vboxguest/ -I/tmp/vbox.0/vboxguest/include -I/tmp/vbox.0/vboxguest/r0drv/linux -D__KERNEL__ -DMODULE -DVBOX -DRT_OS_LINUX -DIN_RING0 -DIN_RT_R0 -DIN_GUEST -DIN_GUEST_R0 -DIN_MODULE -DRT_WITH_VBOX -DVBGL_VBOXGUEST -DVBOX_WITH_HGCM -DRT_ARCH_AMD64 -DVBOX_WITH_64_BITS_GUESTS  -DMODULE  -D"KBUILD_STR(s)=#s" -D"KBUILD_BASENAME=KBUILD_STR(VBoxGuest_linux)"  -D"KBUILD_MODNAME=KBUILD_STR(vboxguest)" -c -o /tmp/vbox.0/.tmp_VBoxGuest-linux.o /tmp/vbox.0/VBoxGuest-linux.c
/tmp/vbox.0/VBoxGuest-linux.c:199:49: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘g_VBoxGuestPciId’
 static const struct pci_device_id __devinitdata g_VBoxGuestPciId[] =
                                                 ^
/tmp/vbox.0/VBoxGuest-linux.c:147:33: warning: ‘g_fInputDeviceRegistered’ defined but not used [-Wunused-variable]
 static bool                     g_fInputDeviceRegistered = false;
                                 ^
In file included from /tmp/vbox.0/r0drv/linux/the-linux-kernel.h:75:0,
                 from /tmp/vbox.0/VBoxGuest-linux.c:27:
include/linux/module.h:138:40: error: ‘__mod_pci__g_VBoxGuestPciId_device_table’ aliased to undefined symbol ‘g_VBoxGuestPciId’
   extern const struct type##_device_id __mod_##type##__##name##_device_table \
                                        ^
/tmp/vbox.0/VBoxGuest-linux.c:209:1: note: in expansion of macro ‘MODULE_DEVICE_TABLE’
 MODULE_DEVICE_TABLE(pci, g_VBoxGuestPciId);
 ^
make[2]: *** [/tmp/vbox.0/VBoxGuest-linux.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [_module_/tmp/vbox.0] Error 2
make: *** [vboxguest] Error 2
Creating user for the Guest Additions.
Creating udev rule for the Guest Additions kernel module.
```

Comment: When I had problems with automatic screen resolution adjustment using Ubuntu inside Virtual Box, installing newer version of Virtual Box and Guest Additions resolved problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I finnally found a solution : 
I had a pretty old version of guest addition (4.1.4) so i downloaded a newer version (4.2.38) [here](http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/4.2.38/) (guest addition.iso) and it worked fine !

Answer (score 0):

Somehow related, I had the same issue after updating to Virtual Box 5.1.18, the installation of guest additions always failed. I finally found that the issue was reported, and the solution was basically just to install a 5.2 version of Virtual Box